# what is the manifest JSON of the bower package management

Tags: frontend, bower

On the Site bower.io,it says "There must be a valid manifest JSON in the current working directory." What does that mean? What is a manifest JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is referring to the `bower.json` file.  This is a a sample of that:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "path/to/main.css",
  "ignore": [
    ".jshintrc",
    "**/*.txt"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "<name>": "<version>",
    "<name>": "<folder>",
    "<name>": "<package>"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "<test-framework-name>": "<version>"
  }
}
```